# How can I increase the number of people viewing my SO questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, views

I am a solo developer and I depend heavily on SO for help. Lately when I post a question, only a few people look at it, and hardly anyone responds. I really need to change this. What can I do to get more views?

Here is a link to a question I recently submitted: 
[Why doesn't jQuery dialog open event fire when .dialog("open") is called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773674/why-doesnt-jquery-dialog-open-event-fire-when-dialogopen-is-called)

Comment: First see How to ask tips from [here](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) and [here](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). Tag your question properly. And make your question clear to understand.

Comment: You could format your title and the first section of your question more clear and easy to read. PS: Also not many people are interested in very specific questions, because it requests a lot knowledge of the context to answer that question (only if that specific question is damn easy, you may well see 10 answers in 5 minutes :) ).

Comment: Try flagging for moderator attention. That'll get someone to look at it. :)

Comment: Thanks to everyone who posted their comments. I will spend some time investigating these comments on Monday.

Answer (score 6):

Looking at your code in Question it could be reduced to these parts causing problem. If you you do this you may sort the problem and if not you may get Answers.

[**Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example**](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 1):

You could place a [bounty on the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) which might do a good bit to get some extra sets of eyes looking at the question.

Alternately, if you blog or do any of those other fancy things, drop in a link and ask for some help.

Looking at the question, the title is well worded (clear, concise etc) and the question doesn't lack the detail needed to have it answered.

Edit: I see that you don't have the rep to post a bounty on it. I left a comment, if you don't get an answer in a few days, leave me a comment and I will drop a bounty on it on your behalf.